# How to automatically generate the list of dataframes (i.e. dfs=[df1, df2, df3, ... , df100])?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

There are several dataframes.

```
df1=pd.DataFrame()
df2=pd.DataFrame()
df3=pd.DataFrame()
df4=pd.DataFrame()
df5=pd.DataFrame()
df6=pd.DataFrame()
df7=pd.DataFrame()
df8=pd.DataFrame()
```

I want to make a list of dataframes.

```
dfs=[df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8]
```

How can I automatically generate this list if the number of df is very large (i.e. df1 ~ df100)?
I tried in several ways, but it did not work well.

Case 1,

```
dfs=[]
dfs.append("df{}".format(i) for i in range(1,9))
dfs

output>> [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x000001D651C9D2E0>]
```

Case 2,

```
dfs=[]
for i in range(1, 9):
    dfs.append("df{}".format(i))
dfs

output>> ['df1', 'df2', 'df3', 'df4', 'df5', 'df6', 'df7', 'df8']
```

In case 2, type(dfs[0]) is not dataframe, but string.

Comment: `dfs = [pd.DataFrame() for _ in range(1, 9)]` or named with a `dict` like `dfs = {f'df{i}': pd.DataFrame() for i in range(1, 9)}`.

Comment: The output of dfs is {'df1': Empty DataFrame  Columns: []  Index: [], ~~}

Comment: You're saying you have a 100 variables already defined, and you're looking for a way to programmatically collect a group of existing variables into a list?

Comment: use `[pd.eval(f"df{x}") for x in range(1,9)]` or you can use simple `eval` but using `eval` is bit controversial

Comment: The dataframe I mentioned is not empty and has many data.  I'm looking for a way to make a list of dataframes.